# Accidently removed "Contextual Menu Items " folder, RightClick not working , How to recover?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I was testing an application called iTrash during which it seems like i have deleted the
"Contextual Menu Items " folder as its no longer present and i can no longer right-click 
anywhere on my Snow Leopard. I don't have any backups. Can someone tell me how i can recover 
that folder or if i can download the files needed to have in that folder (just the original 
ones) to regain the Right-click again?

Comment: it is not still in Trash, is it?

Comment: Doesnt this belong on superuser?

Comment: i wish it was in Trash, but its not. I didn't know this is even possible but it's definitely missing. Maybe if someone can zip the files that are in there and post them i can recreate the Contextual Menu Items folder, put the files in and see if it'll work?

Comment: Other thing that seems to be effected since the screwup is that the Restart/Shutdown keyboard shortcuts no longer work and in the Apple Menu there's no shortcut listed next to Restart/Shutdown! Any suggestions on how i can sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around the problem by reinstalling the 10.6.3 update and also by replacing the Track preference file .plist using an app called Pacifist which allows you to look into MacOSX installation Disk or image and search and extract individual files, in my case the default .plist file for the System Menu Trackpad. glad to see the back of this bizarre predicament.